# Polynomial interpolation of binary vectors

Tags: co.combinatorics, polynomials, algorithms, fourier-transform, interpolation

Let $\mathbb{F}$ be a finite field and let $\boldsymbol{x} = (x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n)$ be $n$
pairwise distinct points in $\mathbb{F}$.

Given the vector $\boldsymbol{y} = (y_1, y_2, \dots, y_n)$, with $y_i \in \{0,1\}$, we can find a polynomial $p(x)$ such that $$p(x_i) = y_i,$$ for $i = 1, \dots, n$.

I recently discovered the [DFT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform) algorithm (here, the values $x_i$ are taken to be the powers of a primitive $n$-th root of unity) to perform this task in $\mathcal{O}(n \log n)$.

1. There exists faster algorithms for the case where the evaluations $y_i$ are either $1$ or $0$?
2. If not, there exists some trick to improve efficiency for this case?

Comment: If the set of $y_i$ for which $y_i = 1$ is sufficiently small, then you can do this quickly using Lagrange interpolation. More generally, if "most" of the $y_i$ values are equal to $0$ (without any constraint on what non-zero values $y_i$ can take), then Lagrange interpolation should be very fast.