# Binary polynomial evaluation

Tags: polynomials, algorithms, fourier-transform

Let $p$ be a prime number and let $P(x) = a_0 + a_1x + a_2x^2 + \dots + a_{n-1}x^{n-1}$ be a polynomial in $\mathbb{Z}_p[x]$ with binary coefficients, i.e., such that $a_i \in \{0,1\}$ for all $i = 0,1,\dots,n-1$. I like to refer to this kind of polynomials them as *binary polynomials*.

The problem of evaluation is defined as follows:
Given $x_1, x_2, \dots, x_{n} \in \mathbb{Z}_p$ and $a_0,a_1, \dots, a_{n-1}$, *polynomial evaluation* consists in computing the values $$y_1 = P(x_1), y_2 = P(x_2), \dots, y_{n} = P(x_{n}),$$ where $p(x)$ is the polynomial $P(x) = a_0 + a_1x + a_2x^2 + \dots + a_{n-1}x^{n-1}$.

I recently discovered the [DFT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform) algorithm (here, the values $x_i$ are taken to be the powers of a primitive $n$-th root of unity) to perform this task in $\mathcal{O}(n \log n)$.

1. There exists faster algorithms for the case that the polynomial $P(x)$ is binary?
2. If not, there exists some trick to improve efficiency for this case?

Comment: You could model an algorithm for evaluating $p(x)$ as a Directed Acyclic Graph where the vertices represent either $0$, $1$, the sum of two previous vertices, or the product of two previous vertices. And then you can try to find the optimal DAG for some polynomials, which represents the optimal program for evaluating that polynomial

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_circuit_complexity

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_evaluation

Comment: Are the $n$ which gives the number of coefficients and the $n$ which gives the number of arguments meant to be the same number?

Comment: How does this question differ from your earlier one, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/408913/polynomial-interpolation-of-binary-vectors ?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Yes, $n$ is the same in both cases as a polynomial of degree $n-1$ is completely and uniquely defined by $n$ points. This is the so called *point-value* representation of the polynomial. The other question referred to polynomial interpolation, which is the analogous problem of polynomial evaluation.